# Constant incorrect name replacement

Tags: iphone

My grandson’s name is Cavan. Siri constantly replaces it with Kevin. I have manually corrected it every single time but Siri isn’t learning. How do I teach him who I’m talking about? I don’t know any Kevins.

Comment: Is this Siri pronunciation or speech to text?